# Who is billed for BigQuery queries?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am still not clear on who is billed for BigQuery queries on my dataset.  If I have shared my dataset with another user and the other user queries it, who pays for those queries?  There was a similar thread  a year ago but I still wasn't confident that I understood who pays in this case.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you own a dataset, you are billed for storage of all of the tables in that dataset. You are also billed for any queries that you run. If another user runs queries against your tables, they are billed, not you.

All queries run in the context of a project, which controls billing. I may be member of multiple projects, but only one project will be billed. If you are using the BigQuery Web UI, the active project determines who gets billed for the query. If you are using the bq command line tool, the default project or the `--project_id` flag determines the billing project.

Comment: what about a personal google users account? If you share a big query dataset with someones gmail account?