# Which project is billed for BigQuery streaming?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have CAN EDIT access to a dataset in another team's project.
We stream data there with insertAll method.

Which project will pay for streaming inserts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Who is billed for BigQuery queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720981/who-is-billed-for-bigquery-queries)

Comment: No, in BigQuery queries you define the project to be billed (http://goo.gl/f9A1Yi). But with streaming inserts this parameter only specifies the destination project (http://goo.gl/0XJwIZ).

Answer (score 2):

The project that owns a table will be billed for streaming. That is, it doesn't matter who does the streaming, it only matters who owns the data.

For example, if you send a post request to:
`https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my_project/datasets/my_dataset/tables/my_table/insertAll?alt=json`

The my_project project will be billed for the streaming request.

Comment: Thanks, that's what we were afraid of ;(  Are there any plans to introduce a parameter to define a billed project? (similar to query request)