# BigQuery: Is it possible it to have the query cost goes to the project owner?

Tags: google-bigquery

I know if any user query data from a dataset, that person will get billed for the query, while the project will get billed for the storage. Is it possible to set it up so the project or billing account which creates the project get billed for the query instead of the person who did the query?

I guess one solution to this is to create a service account and have that service account does the querying through a web app.

[Who is billed for BigQuery queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720981/who-is-billed-for-bigquery-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not the user per se who is being billed for querying data - it is rather project (from which query is being executed) get's billed. Of course if that given user happen to be a billing owner - it means that the user gets billed.
The only way I know to change this is:

1. be added (as Project Viewer at least ) to the project that queryable data is in
2. log into that project and execute query from within that project

Note if you are in Web UI - the active project becomes a billing project. and if you are using bq command line - you need to set default or billing project using respectve flag

Comment: Let say you make an account and create "project1". You attach a billing account to it (billing1) and gave "user1" "Can View" permission level on the project level.

Comment: yes, so now, when user1 will log into Web UI and will make project1 active - he will be able to query table within those datasets that have respective permissions for Project Viewer group. So, important here  - you dont grant permissions to that specific user on dataset level  - because if yo do  - now he will be able to query this dataset from within any project thath he has access to and bill will go to respective one. hope this make sense to you

Comment: Let say you make an account and create "project1". You attach a billing account to it (billing1) and gave "user1" "Can View" permission level on the project level.
1) "user1" have a google account only and tries to access bigquery web UI to query data in "project1" dataset table. Can this user even access google bigquery (need to test this myself)? If he/she can, you are saying the "billing1" will be charge.
2) "user1" have a google account with a billing account "billing2". This person have access to google bigquery for sure. Which billing account will be charged in this case?

Comment: pressed enter too fast on the first one.

Comment: I think I got it. As long as the person is in the project, that project will get billed. But if a user is in another project but query against the table, that other project will get billed.

Comment: yes, that was my point - as long as we interpret above comments same way :o)